# Plotting multiple columns in a pandas line graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, linegraph

I am trying to plot a multiple columns in a line graph with 'Month' as the X axis and each 'Count' as a new line. I want it to have 5 lines, 'Count-18..Count-14'. I tried plotting 1 line as a test but when I run the following code I get the following output with no graph. Any ideas?

```
ax = plt.gca()

DomReg1418.plot(kind='line',x='Month',y='Count-18',ax=ax)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you have a DataFrame with one column to be used as X axis
and other as a source of lines to draw, you should:

- set the index to the "X" column (in your case *Month*),
- run *plot*,
- terminate the command with a semicolon, to block a text message
  concerning the picture object.

The code to do it is:

```
DomReg1418.set_index('Month').plot();
```

For the test, I entered *X* and 3 *Count* columns, for first 6 months
and executed the above command, getting the following result:

[image]